# Single Sign On with a Web Application

Tags: java, angular, single-sign-on

I am try to build a SPA with Angular (>= 6) as a frontend.

The app uses a Java backend for accessing its data out of a database.

Users are managed in an Active Directory.

I have the requirement to use single sign on at the frontend.

So I would expect the user is not required to input username/passwort into the frontend.

Can anyone give me a quick explanation if that is possible? I miss the concept of that because the frontend is running in the browser I do not know how to proceed here.

Authentication at the backend to the Active Directory is not new to me but I have no idea how to get any user credientials from the frontends system inside the frontend without having it by input.

The frontends OS is Windows but the backend is a Linux.

Thanks for help!

Comment: If all the applications run in the browser and redirects to a login page are ok you should have a look at [OIDC](https://openid.net/connect/), otherwise you might need to directly use a more complext  but flexible OAuth 2.0 flow. As an authentication backend I'd suggest using either an identity provider/server like Keycloak or WSO2 or an online service like auth0. Those provide implementations for SSO as well as federation into your AD.

Comment: I do not understand the "login page". There should be no login-page". The user only logs in once at system startup.

Comment: Well, the user needs to be authenticated at some point. If it's his OS login then you need to integrate that as well - an identity provider can help here too.